# Converting String to a DateTime or TimeValue

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem trying to convert a String to a DateTime or TimeValue.
I made a little Windows Form to use as an example. Please take a look at this to see the Form:

[image]

As you can see there is a **TextBox1**.
Also a **Timer1** with an interval of 1000 ms.

What I want is to be able to fill in a time in the textbox (like this format: 22:30:00) and when your desktop reaches this time, it will display a messagebox.

I tried several old posts and tutorials with similar problems but I can't seem to find the solution. Can anyone make a quick example using my screenshot perhaps?

This is the code someone else suggested.

```
Dim tsValue As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero 

If TimeSpan.TryParse(TextBox1.Text.Trim, tsValue) Then 
    If Date.Now.TimeOfDay = tsValue Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Messagebox test {0}", tsValue.ToString)) 
    End If 
End If
```

But for some reason it does not work when I place it in my Timer.

Comment: 1) dont use irrelevant tags 2) dont post pictures elsewhere, post the code you have tried **here**  See [Ask]

Comment: @Plutonix The OP lacks rep to post to a picture because it requires 10 rep. (otherwise though, I agree with your comment).

Comment: @JordySteyaert - In the future, don't put code in comments, it won't format and is hard to read.  Instead, edit your question and add it there (as I just did).

Comment: @Tim Just noticed this, as it is the first time I'm using this website. I updated my Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a variable with the target time (assuming it passes validation) and have your timer check if the target time matches the current time.  Make sure your timer updates the date when the day changes (12:00 AM).

```
Private m_dteTime As DateTime
Private m_dteCurrentDate As Date = DateTime.Now.Date

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    'Validation
    Try
        Dim strHours As String = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 2)
        Dim strMinutes As String = TextBox1.Text.Substring(3, 2)
        Dim strSeconds As String = TextBox1.Text.Substring(6, 2)

        If IsNumeric(strHours) AndAlso IsNumeric(strMinutes) And IsNumeric(strSeconds) Then

            m_dteTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(strHours)).AddMinutes(strMinutes).AddSeconds(strSeconds)

        Else

            m_dteTime = DateTime.MinValue

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If DateTime.Now.Date > m_dteCurrentDate Then

        m_dteCurrentDate = DateTime.Now.Date

    End If

    If m_dteTime.Date = DateTime.Now.Date AndAlso m_dteTime.Hour = DateTime.Now.Hour AndAlso _
       m_dteTime.Minute = DateTime.Now.Minute AndAlso m_dteTime.Second = DateTime.Now.Second Then

        MsgBox("The time is now.")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried your code but a messagebox does not appear when I fill in a time. In what format do I have to enter the time inside the textbox? hh:mm:ss?

Comment: Exactly like your question.  Make sure your timer is at an interval that is less than one second.  An interval of 250 should suffice.

Comment: I changed the interval to 800 and now it works just like I wanted it to. Thank you @NoAlias for your help. Learning something new everyday :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is you're using "=" operator to compare two values which are highly unlikely to be equal. The thing is, you're entering the time value without milliseconds in your TextBox control, but the TimeOfDay function returns current time including milliseconds. Therefore, your message box never gets shown.

Now, there are multiple ways to get around this, but let's keep it simple. If you change "=" to "<=", it will work, but in that case your message box will continue to appear with each timer iteration, so you would have to disable timer right after or just before you show a message box. Depending on what are you trying to achieve, this could or could not be the solution for you.

If you need to keep the timer running, you can remove the millisecond part of the current time before comparing, which will give you one second to do the comparing. Also, in this case you should reduce timer interval to a lower value (500ms should be enough).

Also, if I may suggest, instead of TextBox, you should use DateTimePicker control with Format property set to Time and ShowUpDown property set to True. It will make your life easier as it will automate validation and also avoid uneeded conversions.

Comment: A DateTimePicker would be much better indeed. If you take a look at @NoAllias his code, how would I change the TextBox1.Text.Substring(3, 2) to the value of the DateTimePicker?

Comment: You don't. DateTimePicker has Value property which is of Date data type. That means, you can extract minutes part simply by using DateTimePicker1.Value.Minute or you can convert the value to TimeSpan with DateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks for the information, will try it out on my project. Sounds pretty logical once you learn how to use it